# Bind to static theme in ResourceDictionary

Tags: c#, xaml, silverlight, windows-phone-8

I am trying to create a custom theme for a WP8 app. Not the built-in dark/light theme, but a custom white-label theme. To make it work I have created a static class like:

```
public class Theme : DependencyObject
{
    static Theme()
    {
        CurrentTheme = new DefaultAppTheme();
    }

    public static IAppTheme CurrentTheme { get; set; }
}
```

I can then bind to the static property in a page by first including a reference in the Resource section:

```
<pages:PhoneApplicationPage.Resources>
    <ResourceDictionary>
        <ui:Theme x:Key="Theme"/>
    </ResourceDictionary>
</pages:PhoneApplicationPage.Resources>
```

And finally:

```
<Rectangle Fill="{Binding Path=CurrentTheme.DarkIconBrush, Source={StaticResource Theme}, Mode=OneTime}">
```

So far so good. The only thing left is to do the same thing in the /Themes/Generic.xaml file, but I can't for the life of me figure out how.

I can verify by running the app that the binding above works like a charm. By setting the Theme.CurrentTheme in the App ctor I can change the theme for the app.

How do I bind in Generic.xaml to the color properties of my Theme class? This is what I have tried:

1. Add a Resources section to the ResourceDictionary in Generic.xaml - does not work, as that class doesn't support it
2. Try to declare it as a variable (resource) in Generic.xaml and reference it, like:

   <ui:Theme x:Key="MyTheme"/>

Not sure how the binding syntax would look here.

3. Do some odd attached property binding magic to workaround the issue.

The Generic.xaml is **not** in the App project, it is in a User controls project (library). Otherwise I could add it to the App class' Resource section.

Answer (score 0):

Disclaimer: I'm not a WP developer, I develop for the ordinary desktop browser Silverlight.

My mental model how **default styles**, **templates**, **generic.xaml**, and **themes** work together is the following (and this might work for you too):

In order for my (templated) custom controls to work properly throughout an application the framework must be able to find the default templates. Therefore default styles with those templates are included in generic.xaml.
**Mental model**: generic.xaml is in no way involved in theming, its only concern is to provide the templates (and default settings) for my custom types, so my application UI is technically usable.

It is my responsibility that my default template actually binds to and makes use of public dependency properties concerned with the control appearance: Background, BorderBrush, BorderThickness, Foreground, Padding

And maybe I have to add one or two properties myself to allow customization of my control:

```
[StyleTypedProperty( Property = "ToggleButtonStyle", StyleTargetType = typeof( ToggleButton ) )]
[StyleTypedProperty( Property = "DropDownBackgroundStyle", StyleTargetType = typeof( Border ) )]
public class DropDownButton : Control
{
    ...

    public Style ToggleButtonStyle
    {
        get { return (Style) GetValue( ToggleButtonStyleProperty ); }
        set { SetValue( ToggleButtonStyleProperty, value ); }
    }

    public static readonly DependencyProperty ToggleButtonStyleProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register( "ToggleButtonStyle", typeof( Style ), typeof( DropDownButton ), null );

    public Style DropDownBackgroundStyle
    {
        get { return (Style) GetValue( DropDownBackgroundStyleProperty ); }
        set { SetValue( DropDownBackgroundStyleProperty, value ); }
    }

    public static readonly DependencyProperty DropDownBackgroundStyleProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register( "DropDownBackgroundStyle", typeof( Style ), typeof( DropDownButton ), null );

}
```

**Mental model**: Customizability / Themability is something I have to built into my custom controls.

If in a concrete application (and a different assembly) I need my controls to follow a theme (without the need to set a style explicitly for each and every occurrence) I have to provide a separate default style, but that new default style only sets those properties that are concerned with appearance:
So I would add something like this to my App.xaml:

```
<Application.Resources>
    <ResourceDictionary>
        <ui:Theme x:Key="Theme"/>
        <Style TargetType="ToggleButton" x:Key="ThemedToggleButtonStyle">
            <Setter Property="Background" Value="{Binding Path=CurrentTheme.DarkIconBrush, Source={StaticResource Theme}, Mode=OneTime}"/>
        </Style>
        <!-- implicity default style for all ToggleButtons -->
        <Style TargetType="ToggleButton" BasedOn="{StaticResource ThemedToggleButtonStyle}"/>
        <!-- implicity default style for all DropDownButtons -->
        <Style TargetType="controls:DropDownButton">
            <Setter Property="ToggleButtonStyle" Value="{StaticResource ThemedToggleButtonStyle}"/>
            <Setter Property="Background" Value="{Binding Path=CurrentTheme.DarkIconBrush, Source={StaticResource Theme}, Mode=OneTime}"/>
        </Style>
    </ResourceDictionary>
</Application.Resources>
```

**Mental model**: For a theme to be applied in one of my concrete apps I have to "add a second layer" of implicit default styles. It is the concern of my concrete app to provide that layer, not the concern of my custom-controls-assemby.

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to respond. I agree with you on the overall structure. I have done many WPF and Silverlight apps before, as well as WP. This time is the first time putting themeable controls in a separate assembly. I did get it to work with a 'BindingResolutionHelper' class that meant I could do bindings in styles, but for performance reasons I did not go with that solution.

Comment: Also, I assume your suggestion will work. The one thing I am less fond of is that a third party developer using my library would have to copy all styles to their App.xaml class. But I guess I will have to live with that. Windows Phone Runtime is better here, as it supports the "ThemeResource" (as opposed to StaticResource).

Comment: @HenrikOscarsson: Well, you can still bundle all the themed implicit styles (that I so carelessly threw into the App.xaml) into one single ResourceDictionary file in your assembly and just include it as a MergedDictionary in the App.xaml of the other project. And the overhead for other developers will shrink into a single line.